# Jquery Animate callback running several times. Why?

Tags: jquery, loops, callback, jquery-animate

Here I am with my first post. My issue is that the callback function of my main animate isn't running one time as it is suppose to, but severeal times (7). I do not understand why. 
Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

```
$('#wrapper li').click(function(){

   //Here I declare my varaiables

   $('#wrapper li').slice(startLi,endLi).animate({
            "left": '-='+leftDistance},
            "fast",function() {
                    $('.class').animate({
            "left": "+=200px"},
            "slow");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to change that behavior by putting that before `animate` function:

```
$('selector').stop().animate(....)
```

Also see:

- [Quick Tip: Prevent Animation Queue Buildup](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup%5C)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete) for `animate()` says the callback function is called once for each animated element.

If you animate seven elements, it will be called seven times.

Comment: Hello Frédéric, Safraz's tip helped me solve my problem, and your info helped me understanding it. Thank you very much!